# Manually edit cells in a dataframe column with reference to a row

Tags: r

Following on from previous questions, I want to manually change dates when formatted in the wrong format.  Using the example dataframe:

```
ID <- c(101,102,103,104,105,106,107)
dob <- c("20/04/2001","29/10/2000","September 1 2012","15/11/00","20.01.1999","April 20th 1999", "04/08/01")
df <- data.frame(ID, dob)
```

Having identified which dates are in the incorrect format (by highlighting NAs when there are dates in the wrong), I then want to **manually edit the dob column**.

How do I do this:
a. To ensure the resulting dates are recognised by R.
b. By referencing the ID column and not the relative position of the cell (e.g. not column, row number).

For example:
ID 103 becomes 01/09/2012
ID 105 becomes 20/01/1999
ID 106 becomes 01/04/1999

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, if your variable is a `factor` (as it is the case in your example), you'll have to convert it as `character` first :

```
df$dob <- as.character(df$dob)
```

Then, you shouldn't modify your data by row number, but by selecting the value to be changed. Something like this :

```
df$dob[df$dob=="September 1 2012"] <- "01/09/2012"
df$dob[df$dob=="April 20th 1999"] <- "20/04/1999"
```

An alternative syntax is to use `within` :

```
df <- within(df, {
    dob <- as.character(dob)
    dob[dob=="September 1 2012"] <- "01/09/2012"
    dob[dob=="April 20th 1999"] <- "20/04/1999"
})
```

Once your dates are all in exactly the same format, you'll have to convert them to one of the date classes from base R or from a package. Take a look at the `strptime` help page, for example.